# How to use fprintf() to print a line at the beginning of a previously created .txt file?

Tags: file, printf

I don't want to create a new file and print the new line first then copy the old data into the new file.

Comment: You don't have a choice. Files are a stream of bytes and have no concept of lines. Unless the new data is the same length as the old, you must rewrite the whole file.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention ".txt" file. Would the answer be any different in case of .txt files?

Comment: No. Text files are also streams of bytes that just happen to be human-readable.